# How to handle deeplink URL with in my Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I working with firebase deeplink. I need to know how to handle deeplink URL with in my Application. If i use intent with in getInvitation method, it open the app again and redirect to that URL.

I want to open that URL with in my application and with out open application once again.

Here is my code :

```
new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

           Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
            String deepLink1 = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(deepLink1)));
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);

            Log.d("DeepLink", "getInvitation: deep link found.");                                 
        } else {
            Log.d("GetInvitation", "getInvitation: no deep link found.");
        }
   });
```

deeplink1 will be like : https://xxxxx.app.goo.gl/yyyyy"

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: When i click a URL link from Email, it redirect to the my application. but it'll open twice in my app.

Comment: Please share the code in your question